# How to combine HOG and Covariance based detection methods?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, histogram, covariance

I want to combine two detection algorithms, HOG and Covariance method, to improve the detection performance. I know how HOG works and how Covariance works but, I want to know how to combine these methods to obtain a better detection performance. I'm planning to implement in OpenCV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common point here is probability density map.
Compute probability density maps for each of your methods, then sum ( or multipy) values, normalize, and you'll have combined probability density map for your object.

Comment: Is there any other possible methods which enables the combination of these two algorithms?

Comment: You may also apply committee method (combine results by logical AND). This will assume detection true if both detectors shows true (reduce false positives). Or if you want to reduce false negatives, combine results by logical OR. But probabilistic fusion is still better approach.